# What is a HTREEITEM?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to debug some Tree View code, and I want to check that the `HTREEITEM` returned by `CTreeCtrl.InsertItem` is valid in memory.

However I cannot find any documentation for `HTREEITEM` in any of the places I usually check (Google, MSDN, Coworkers), only a whole bunch of people asking the same question.

Do you know what `HTREEITEM` is defined as? Do you know any good links that detail the internal structure of a `HTREEITEM`?

*I am working in C++, but C references would also be helpful.*

Comment: Sounnds like something that belongs to a particular framework, not the C++ language itself. Please add information about which framework you're using.

Comment: It's just a handle so it should be opaque to you. You can just check if it's a valid handle or not (for anything else you have all TVs functions to manage them).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just an opaque handle to a tree item in the default [Tree View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) controls on Windows. You can acquire handles using e.g. [`TVM_INSERTITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773733%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), they are used in other functions then for referencing the items.

The handle is defined in `CommCtrl.h` (part of the Windows SDK) like this:

```
struct _TREEITEM;
typedef struct _TREEITEM *HTREEITEM;
```

This is also the essence of an opaque handle: you only know that it references some data (a `struct`, in this case) but you don't know the definition of the data.

Comment: To answer the original question: what InsertItem returns is valid, unless it is NULL (as per MSDN).

Comment: Ok, I guess I need to google Opaque Handles next then. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin The underlying TV_Item's memory is trashed (we think by another thread) so i wanted to double check, but thanks.

Comment: @sji: I just extended my answer to show how `HTREEITEM` is (currently) defined and added a small remark regarding opaque handles.

Comment: You're unfortunately SOL.  You could try putting a watchpoint on the address, but there are no guarantees that there is even *any* data behind that opaque pointer.

Comment: @Martin Been at it for 3 days, shouldn't my luck have come back by now? OP: thanks, this answers my question.